# How to Deploy Hyperledger Block Chain to IBM Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, blockchain, hyperledger

Before I jump onto the question directly, I would like to talk about how I encountered this question.

Basically, I'm working with the IBM blockchain technology right now, not only to use the block chain service in Bluemix, but also to modify the Hyperledger peer source code. You can find the Hyperledger project from https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric. It's a Linux platform app written by GO.

After the modification, we had a testing at local vagrant VM servers. All the changes are fine.

Now I try to deploy the updated code to IBM Bluemix via CF App channel. The action failed in compile phase because the basic environment is missing.

Here come my questions:

1. For bluemix, when I start the Block Chain service, what actually happens behind? Does bluemix start a few VM for me to run the peer nodes?
2. Anyone has ever tried to push peer via cf app channel? How to settle the buildpack for peer node?
3. When the peer node is running, it's listening on 3 ports other than 8080. In my local VM server it's fin. But how can I enable those ports in bluemix?

Thanks for your ideas and contribution.

Comment: The Bluemix environment runs the fabric and provides you some peers and security user profiles to work with. You cannot push fabric changes today.  You can write chaincode and deploy it to those peers. The Bluemix deployment is also several commit numbers behind hyperledger, so if you use some some newer features in your contract (like GetTxnTimestamp for example), it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

We thought about running Hyperledger node as an application in Cloud Foundry. It possible to create buildpack with Go, RocksDB, executable files for Docker and other necessary dependencies included. Nevertheless there are several challenges in configuration:

1. In addition to “peer” application, the Docker demon should also be started inside CF container (I haven’t been testing if Docker works inside CF container)
2. As far as CF application by default exposes just 1 network port - We cannot start REST endpoint in the same container where validation peer is started. Workaround - we can run “Membership service”, “Validation peer” and “REST client” as different applications in CF using `-c` option at application deploy time.
3. CF Router supports limited number of protocols, it possible that the will be an issues on this level either.

On an application level there is a problem with Enrolment Certificate (it can be issued just once), in case if CF restarts your application - Validation Peer will not be able to apply for another Enrolment certificate using the same credentials. 
Workaround - It possible to save Certificates in external persistent storage and load them at start time. In any case VP will have just 1 instance in CF (scalability will not be used)

As a result we can hardly use such CF benefits like scalability and automatic failover without customisation to Fabric core.

Comment: Hi, my apologies in advance for I am very new to hyperledger as well. May i know how do you managed to open multiple ports to your Peer in Cloud Foundry?

Comment: Right now you cannot open more then one port in public Cloud Foundry deployments. But it should be possible to deploy Fabric components as separate applications: Membership service as an application with 50051 port open, Validation peer can expose just one port 30303, Client or not validation peer will open port for REST requests. As a result each of these components will use just one network port in Cloud Foundry.

Comment: I'm assuming we are talking about Hyperledger fabric 0.6. I'm not terribly familiar with CloudFoundry, but I'm not sure what you are trying to do is possible in a sensible manner. Fabric 0.6 peers manage their chaincode execution environments themselves - i.e. the lifecycle of the Docker containers that they use for chaincode execution. Can a container in CF do that? I know that "Docker nesting" is possible, but does CF support this? (Let alone the fabric environment.) What worked for us is setup and deployment into VMs (AWS). That leaves in place most of the known "deployment logic".

Comment: CF should be able to do this as of early 2017 because it has container-to-container networking so can enable multiple ports.   Also multiple external ports are an experimental features supportable with the TCP router.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with above instructions, Docker works inside CF container only when we have peer application.rest you [IBMBluemix](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-deploy-sample-application-ibm-blockchain-platform/index.html) should have proper VM configuration as CF have limited ports.